# Finding the multiplicative order of elements in $F_7$

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields

In $F_7$, why is $6$ the multiplicative order of $3$ ?

Comment: Just test the powers of $3$ mod 7. The first positive power for which you get 1 is the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because (everything is done modulo $\;7\;$ )

$$3^2=2\;,\;\;3^3=-1\;,\;\;3^6=1$$